# Program to print the alphabets before and after the blank space in a sentence

Tags: java, char

**Example**- Input:- India is a great nation 
              Output:- a and i, s and a, a and  g, t and n

```
public class PrintSpace
{
    public void accept(String str)
    {
        char ch='\u0000';
        int i=0;
        int l=0;
        l=str.length();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            ch=str.charAt(i);
            if(ch==" ")
            {
                System.out.print((i-1)+"and"+(i+1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.print( str.charAt(i-1)+"and"+str.charAt(i+1));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public static void accept(String str)
    {
        char ch='\u0000';
        int i=0;
        int l=0;
        l=str.length();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            ch=str.charAt(i);
            if(ch == ' ')
            {
                System.out.println(str.charAt(i-1)+" and "+str.charAt(i+1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obliged to you as well, Shruti :)

Answer (score 1):

char cannot be compared to String.

**replace**

```
if(ch == " ") 
 {
 }
```

**with**

```
if(ch == ' ')
 {
 }
```

> You are printing the index, not the character,
>
> use `str.charAt(i- 1) + " and "+ str.charAt(i + 1)`

```
char ch='\u0000';
int i=0;
int l=0;
String str = "India is a great nation";
l=str.length();
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
     ch=str.charAt(i);
     if(ch==' ')
       {
         System.out.println(str.charAt(i-1)+"and"+str.charAt(i+1));
       }
   }
```